# How dense are $\{2^m3^n:m,n\in\Bbb Z\}$ in $\Bbb R^+$?

Tags: real-analysis, transcendental-numbers

How dense is $X=\{2^m3^n:m,n\in\Bbb Z\}$ in $\Bbb R^+$?

I could write the question more precisely but this would probably be counterproductive as someone answering this question would probably know better than I how to do so.

I guess I might ask if $x$ is some arbitrary real number, does every arbitrarily small ball around it contain some value in $X$?

I have a hunch based upon some prior reading that this is related to Baker's theorem, but this may be misplaced.

I didn't know what to tag - so please do edit.

Comment: You mean "dense" in the topological sense? Since $\frac{\log 3}{\log 2}$ is irrational, $X$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: Thanks @DanielFischer that's all I needed I think. What topologies other than as a subset of $\Bbb R$ would make sense here? P.S. Were you away for a while?

Comment: I don't see how this set is dense. How would you approximate, say, $7$?

Comment: I was thinking $2+3=5$ so that would be a bad example, then realized it was multiplication instead of addition...sorry for changing the number unnecessarily.

Comment: @Math1000 $2,3,4,6,\frac{64}9,\ldots$

Comment: Also for $y\in [1,2]$ and $k$, the size of $n,m$ needed so that $|y-\frac{2^n}{3^m}|\le 1/k$ is understood in term of the Diophantine approximation / irrationality measure of $\frac{\log 3}{\log 2}$

Comment: Thanks @reuns for picking up on that slight nuance in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Details of [Daniel Fisher](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83702/daniel-fischer) comment.

$Y=\{m \log 2 +n \log 3 \mid (m,n) \in \mathbb Z^2\}$ is an [additive subgroup](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_of_Real_Numbers_is_Discrete_or_Dense) of $\mathbb R$. Hence it is either dense or discrete (as all additive subgroup of the reals is).

If $Y$ was discrete, it would exists $a > 0$ such that for all $y \in Y$, it exists $p \in \mathbb Z$ such that $y = pa$. And $\log 2, \log 3 \in Y$ implies that $\frac{\log 2}{\log 3}$ is rational and therefore that it exists $(r,s) \in \mathbb Z^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ such that $2^r3^s =1$. That can't be as $2,3$ are coprime numbers.

Finally $Y$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ and $X$ dense in $\mathbb R_+$ as $x \mapsto e^x$ is continuous.