# Is there some $f_{2,3}:\Bbb R^+\to S^1$ such that $f_{2,3}(x)=f_{2,3}(2x)=f_{2,3}(3x)$?

Tags: functions, complex-numbers, equivalence-relations

Let $f_2(x)=x^{2\pi i/\log2}$

Then I think we have that $f_2(x)=f_2(2x)$

And if we set $f_3(x)=x^{2\pi i/\log3}$

then we have that $f_3(3x)=f_3(x)$

Is there some way to combine these so that $f_{2,3}(x)=f_{2,3}(2x)=f_{2,3}(3x)$ but other natural number inputs are distinct?

(Of course this is a symmetric transitive and reflexive equivalence relation so when I say other natural numbers are distinct, I mean all 5-rough positive integers give distinct results.)

Comment: What is $f$ and what is $f_{2,3}$ ?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch There is no $f$ and the question asks for $f_{2,3}$. I corrected possibly ambiguous title.

Comment: But you say $f_2(x)=f(2x)$ ?

Comment: Which domain do $f_2, f_3, f_{2,3}$ have? $\mathbb R_{>0}$ or $\mathbb N_{>0}$?

Comment: @punctureddusk I intended $\Bbb N^+$ but in truth the positive dyadic and ternary rationals $\Bbb Z[\frac16]^+$ would be ideal... and I was looking for continuity in truth so your answer $\Bbb R\to\Bbb C$ is revealing, but in light of that I should probably accept your answer and re-ask something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a continuous $f : \mathbb R_{>0} \to \mathbb C$ with the property that $f(2x) = f(3x) = f(x)$ for all $x$, then $f$ is constant. This is because the set $2^{\mathbb Z} 3^{\mathbb Z}$ is dense in $\mathbb R_{>0}$. (Which is because $\log 3 / \log 2$ is irrational.)

Comment: I think OP is looking for an $f:\mathbb N\to S^1$ but I am confused

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch $S^1\subsetneq\Bbb C$

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3483923/how-dense-are-2m3nm-n-in-bbb-z-in-bbb-r) for details on the arguments.

Comment: Ah, right. domain $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Here you go: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3492483/